# How to insert text to beginning of multiple files using a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The following code will append text in the end of each `.txt` file in the folder but how can I insert the text in the beginning of each file instead?

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do type append_me >> %%a
```

Comment: The definition of "append" includes the notion of "at the end" so it is incompatible with the notion of "in the beginning".  Therefore, your question does not make sense in English.

Comment: Thank you for correction. I fixed the grammar. Hopefully there's no typos anymore.

Comment: `for %%a in (*.txt) do copy insert_me+"%%a" temp.tmp & move /Y temp.tmp "%%a"`

Comment: Thank you. That did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a better way to do it, but you can do it with something like:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do type insert_me > "%temp%\toinsert" & type "%i" >> "%temp%\toinsert" & move /Y "%temp%\toinsert" "%i"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, some of which I want to show you:

1. The simplest approach is to use `copy` and `+` (as [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560) already suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265435/how-to-insert-text-to-beginning-of-multiple-files-using-a-bat-file#comment73601691_43265435)):

   ```cmd
   for %%a in ("*.txt") do (
       copy "insert_me.txt"+"%%~a" "%%~a.tmp" /B
       move /Y "%%~a.tmp" "%%~a"
   )
   ```
2. Relying on redirection, you could do this to insert the text:

   ```cmd
   for %%a in ("*.txt") do (
       > "%%~a.tmp" type "insert_me.txt"
       >>"%%~a.tmp" type "%%~a"
       move /Y "%%~a.tmp" "%%~a"
   )
   ```
3. Or this, using `copy` instead of `>`-redirection.

   ```cmd
   for %%a in ("*.txt") do (
       copy "insert_me.txt" "%%~a.tmp"
       >>"%%~a.tmp" type "%%~a"
       move /Y "%%~a.tmp" "%%~a"
   )
   ```